# For loop on Subset of Files

Tags: linux, bash

```
Cell1.1.annot.gz
Cell1.2.annot.gz
Cell1.3.annot.gz
Cell1.4.annot.gz
Cell1.5.annot.gz
Cell2.1.annot.gz
         .
         .
         .
Cell3.5.annot.gz
```

Making for a total of 3 X 5 = 15 files. I would like to run a python script on them. However, the catch is that each number (clarified here:`Cell2.NUMBER.annot.gz`) has to be matched to another file in a separate directory. I have code that works below, although it only works for one Cell file at a time. How can I automate this so it works for all files? (So `Cell1...Cell3`?)

```
for i in `seq 1 5`; 
do python script.py --file1 DNA_FILE.${i} --file2 Cell1.${i}.annot.gz --thin-annot --out Cell1.${i} ;done
```

Comment: `echo Cell{1..3}.{1..5}.annot.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another loop?

```
for c in 1 2 3
do  for i in 1 2 3 4 5
    do python script.py --file1 DNA_FILE.${i} --file2 Cell${c}.${i}.annot.gz --thin-annot --out Cell${c}.${i}
    done
done
```